# Angular: passing object to different view in same controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am working on an Ionic app where, I need to pass an item (json object) to a view and bind the items there.

I've gone through a lot of similar questions, likely:

[Unable to access $scope variable within same controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644563/unable-to-access-scope-variable-within-same-controller)

[AngularJS: Pass an object into a state using ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632255/angularjs-pass-an-object-into-a-state-using-ui-router?rq=1)

But, seems like none is working in my case.

Here is my HTML markup of `index.html` page (from where I'm passing `item`):

```
<div class="list card slide-in" ng-repeat="item in posts track by $index">
    <h2 ng-bind="item.title" class="assertive"></h2>
    //comes inside ng-repeat loop; I'm passing the whole json object as parameter to next view
    <button class="button button-full" ng-click="getPostDetail(item);"> Read More </button>
</div>
```

Html Markup of `posts.html` page (where I need to access `item`):

```
<ion-view view-title="Read More ">
    <ion-content class="card-background-page ">
        <div class="list padding-20">
            <h2 ng-bind="selectedPost.title" class="assertive"></h2>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

My Config:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, localStorageServiceProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('tabs.posts', {
  url: "/posts",
  params: {
      obj: null // as per other suggestion, added a param here
  },
  views: {
      'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/post.html",
          controller: 'main'
      }
  }
})
```

My Controller:

```
app.controller('main', function ($scope, $http, $state, $ionicModal, $location, $stateParams, localStorageService) {
    $scope.getPostDetail = function (data) {
        var selectedPost = data;
        $state.go("tabs.posts", { obj:  selectedPost });
    }

})
```

On click of button, the Posts View loads successfully, but no content is bound i.e. the view is blank

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, `selectedPost` needs to be on `$scope`. Otherwise it cannot be accessed from the view. So something like this.

```
    $scope.getPostDetail = function (data) {
        $scope.selectedPost = data;
        $state.go("tabs.posts", { obj:  selectedPost });
    }
```

Comment: I've already tried passing it to `$scope.selectedPost` (even though, both views share same controller), gives the same output.